# How to query date from mongodb using graphql?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I am trying to find documents by DateTime.

I have the following sample of mongo document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df8ea55ac02282c15917e46"),
    "title" : "Bán gấp căn 01 DT 62m2 căn góc, giá 1,05 tỷ. LH C Nga 0979441985",
    "address" : "La Khê - Hà Đông",
    "avatar" : "https://file4.batdongsan.com.vn/crop/200x200/2019/12/07/20191207173723-31f3_wm.jpg",
    "price" : "1.05 Tỷ",
    "lat" : 20.9719924926758,
    "lon" : 105.756340026855,
    "id" : 15504225,
    "area" : "62 m²",
    "cat" : "Bán căn hộ chung cư",
    "date" : "17/12/2019",
    "room" : 2,
    "DateTime" : ISODate("2019-12-17T22:00:36.136+08:00")
}
```

I have defined a schema:

```
const sellType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name:'Sell',
    fields: () => ({
        _id:{type:GraphQLString},
        id:{type:GraphQLString},
        title:{type:GraphQLString},
        address:{type:GraphQLString},
        avatar:{type:GraphQLString},
        price:{type:GraphQLString},
        DateTime:{type:GraphQLDateTime}
    })
})
```

I have also defined the root query:

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name:'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        property_for_sell_by_datetime:{
            type: sellType,
            args:{DateTime:{type:GraphQLDateTime}},
            resolve(parent, args){
                return sell.find({DateTime:new Date(args.DateTime)})
            }
        }
    }
})
```

But I don't know why I cannot find any document using:

```
{
  property_for_sell_by_datetime(DateTime:"2019-12-17T14:00:36.136Z"){
    _id
    DateTime
  }
}
```

Edit:
I tired to use `findOne`. It works. But `find` is not working

Edit2:
I need to define type as GraphQLList

Comment: I have tried to use findOne. It works. But Why?

Answer (score 0):

to use find instead of findOne, I need to define the type as GraphQLList